# In Xcode 4.5 "Show Live Issues" no longer works

Tags: ios, xcode, llvm, xcode4.5

I found it to be very useful that Xcode would show compiler warnings as I wrote code. For instance: if I wrote "ldksjfksdj" I'd expect to immediately see  a red exclamation mark icon and the warning, `use of undeclared identifier`. But now with Xcode 4.5 I only see that warning after I compile the project. And then, after I've compiled it, see the error, and delete "ldksjfksdj", the warning doesn't disappear immediately the way it used to. It will only disappear after I compile it again. This is profoundly annoying and not helpful. Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Are you using Beta Xcode 4.5....

Comment: +1 In my case it displays the errors as I am typing. Of course it takes a little bit of time but it is as I am typing.

Comment: i'm using the newest update, 4.5.2.

Comment: Have you the "live issue" check in the preferences/general settings ? I am also using 4.5.2

Comment: Yes that's checked, but doesn't solve the issue..

Comment: Look at the Issues Navigator. Are any issues listed about your project? Maybe it needs a little updating. Have you tried a new, clean project to verify it works there?

Comment: yeah i've tried that. doesn't work. i even re-installed Xcode.

Comment: Strangely only happens with one project. Live issues woks fine with others..

Comment: If it only happens in one project, try this: go to Organizer -> Projects, and delete derived data.

Comment: I think I am having this same issue? Tends happen for large projects. Happened in Xcode 4 and still happens in Xcode 5.

Answer (score 3):

Under File > Project Settings in the Build tab, there is an option for 'Show live issues for source code'. There are also options for 'Show issues for active scheme only' and 'Show all issues'. 'Show live issues for source code' should be set to enabled. These are the live issues settings at the project level.

Hope that solves your problem.